# How to grant a developer access to my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I basically want them to have access to create/modify anything that they create, but not really able to modify/delete existing resources.

Or in some other way put them in their own bubble.

I actually got AWS certified associate in architecture, so should have some idea of whatever you say. I forgot most of what I learned for the test.

For now I made them a PowerUser.

Thanks!

Comment: AWS has no concept of "existing resources" or of "who" created resources.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no elegant solution for this in a shared AWS account. If you need this level of separation, creating a sub-account is the way to achieve this.

Comment: yikes, thanks, i might have to do some serious studying to try to figure out how to best handle this.


for now, i granted way too many privileges.


i started by granting PowerUser. then SystemAdministrator. Then created a new policy to allow creation of roles. Then finally granted all IAM. that, finally, was enough. for now. but...def not what i wanted.

Comment: Actually - there are tagging polices to do so

Answer (score 0):

> but not really able to modify/delete existing resources.

You can use resource and/or identity tags and then allow or deny actions based on tags.  E. g. you can deny any action for tags env=production. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html

You can create simple or more complex [Tag Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_tag-policies-getting-started.html) to enforce consistent resource tagging.

And there is a way to enforce the owner identity in a tag, so you can allocate costs. (just search the inet for it if you want)

> Or in some other way put them in their own bubble.

To keep it simple the development is usually done on a separate (organizational) account and the developers shoup deliver a deployment script/procedure to deploy the resources to other stages (cloudformation, terraform,..) .

> . i started by granting PowerUser. then SystemAdministrator

This is something... the developers should not need. If so, you could implement an SCP (Service control policies) to limit even the admin users (deny disabling the cloudtrail, access to sensitive kms, modify roles with certain tags,.. .)